# Power apps pen input image save to CRM notes

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, powerapps

I am working on powerapps which will integrate with CRM and create records in it. As part of this I wanted to save the peninput as a note in CRM. But CRM only takes images as base64 encoded. In powerapps the output of pen input is not base64 encoded instead it is a URI to a local blob storage.

If I save the local blob storage then, in CRM it will not show the image.

There is a way to do it in SharePoint but that is not working for CRM.

Is there a way to save the peninput to CRM?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Have you figured out a way?

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to.